# What is the fastest way to plot a huge amount of lines in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In a project I'm working on I have to plot a huge amount of lines into one figure. Therefore I am using a for loop like this:

```
for i in xrange(0,len(x)):
     ax[plotId].plot(x[i],y[i],color = usedColors[i])
```

Unfortunately, this loop needs around 0.8 seconds which is to much for me since I use matplotlib in an interactive way (the user is able to change the plot with integrated buttons. Is there an alternative way to do this? For example write all the related data in a list while loading the GUI:

```
l = [x[0],y[0],usedColors[0],x[1],x[2]....]
```

and use this list somehow to write the data in plot() without using a loop (which is not working because ax[plotId].plot cannot interpret this list in a proper way):

```
ax[plotId].plot(l)
```

Any ideas?

**Update:** 
I was looking for `LineCollection`

Comment: What is in `x` and `y`?  I.e. are they lists of lists so `x[i]` is itself a list? If not you're plotting single points which you don't need to do.  As to the question, do the interactive buttons ever change the data or just change things like color, etc?  If the latter, you don't have to re-plot the data you can just keep the Line2D object and change its color.  There is plenty of documentation on matplotlib's objects.

Comment: You want `LineCollection`

Comment: @Ajean: x and y are lists of lists, so I plot lines. By pressing the buttons the user changes the data and colors.

Comment: @tcaswell: thanks for this hint! I will test LineCollection today!

Comment: I understand this is a year old, but it would have been nice to actually answer your question with an example, and ideally a mini-benchmark.